# How to store text "00012345678" and keep the zero's in Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to store text like: "00012345678" and keep the zero's in Sharepoint list?

Gr. P

Comment: Are you using "Single line of text" column or "Number" column?

Comment: single line of text column

Answer (score 1):

According to the tests, the value keeps the zeros in 'Single line of text' column and 'Multiple line of text' column.
The zeros are automatically hide in 'Number' column.